# Populating TextBox, The data type is not valid for the boolean operation

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

I got a ComboBox with a table as data source, ID as a value member and a name as a display member.
Selecting a name from the ComboBox should populate 6 TextBoxes with data.

Exception:

```
The data type is not valid for the boolean operation. [ Data type (if known) = int,Data type (if known) = nvarchar ]
```

Code:

```
void FillComboBox()
{

//Fill Combo Box

    SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(" SELECT CustomerID, Name FROM Customers", clsMain.con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    cBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    cBox1.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
    cBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
}

public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clsMain.con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\Sales.sdf";
    clsMain.con.Open();

    FillComboBox();
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

//Save Button

    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = " INSERT INTO Customers (Name, Phone1, Phone2, Address, Notes) VALUES (@Name, @Phone1, @Phone2, @Address, @Notes) ";
    cmd.Connection = clsMain.con;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txt2.Text.Trim());
    if (txt3.Text != "")
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone1", Convert.ToInt32(txt3.Text));
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone1", Convert.DBNull);
    }
    if (txt4.Text != "")
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone2", Convert.ToInt32(txt4.Text));
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone2", Convert.DBNull);
    }
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txt5.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txt6.Text.Trim());



    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Data stored.");
}

private void cBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {

        String Code = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID=" + cBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(Code, clsMain.con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);


        txt1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerID"].ToString();
        txt2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
        txt3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Phone1"].ToString();
        txt4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Phone2"].ToString();
        txt5.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
        txt6.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Notes"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Table Details:

[image]

Comment: `CustomerID` is an int, and you're passing a string.  I've not used SQL CE, but you might try this:  `"SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID=" + cBox1.SelectedValue` (i.e., get rid of the single quotes in your SQL query).

Comment: Thanks, But now i got this exception instead.
`There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 53,Token in error = Data ]`

Comment: Please post the query string you used.  Also, step into you code with the debugger and see what the value is for `cBox1.SelectedValue` when you construct your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on my comment (with the caveat that I have never worked with SQL CE, but I'm pretty sure (99.9%) that this is correct).

In you SQL query string, you surround the customer id with single quotes (`'`).  You use single quotes in SQL ("nomral" SQL at least) for character (char\varchar etc) and date values.  You pass numeric values without single quotes.

You didn't indicate what line was giving you the exception, but based on the table structure and what you are doing (you gave good detail in your question, by the way), it seems that the error message is telling you that you're trying to compare an int to a varchar, and that's not allowed (because they are different data types, as the error indicates).

To resolve this, simply remove the single quotes from the value in your WHERE clause and construct your query as follows:

```
String Code = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID=" + cBox1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked just fine i'm not sure about the second exception though.
I'm getting the error on this line `da.Fill(ds);`
I'm not sure about query string you mean connection string ?

Comment: You're welcome.  By query string I mean the SQL query your passing to the adapter. Are you still getting the exception when you call `Fill`?

Comment: Oh sorry right the one you gave me a while ago `String Code = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID=" + cBox1.SelectedValue;`
And yea i'm still getting the exception.

Comment: Edit: When replacing `if (cBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)` with `if (cBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)` I get no errors but when selecting first selection from ComboBox it doesn't populate TextBoxes

Comment: Do you know what the value of `SelectedValue` is when the `SelectedIndex` is 0?  Index 0 should be the first customer in your ComboBox, which based on your table schema should have a value of 1.  One additional thing to try - add `.ToList()` in your query string (`cBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()`), as `SelectedValue` is returning an `Object`.  I doubt that is the issue though, as it works otherwise, but it won't hurt to try.

Comment: Yea you right the value should be 1 but instead it's `{System.Data.DataRowView}`, To string didn't work too.
Maybe i can change the populating code and start over.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to populate the `ComboBox`?

Comment: I just noticed that you're seeing `{System.Data.DataRowView}`. Your populating code looks correct.  Try using `SelectedItem.ToString()` instead of `SelectedValue.ToString()`.  What is the `DropDownStyle` of your ComboBox?

Comment: Yea i tried that too, Same issue, DropDownStyle = DropDown by default. But really you already done more than enough, Wasted lots of your time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Its working for me.
I am having some customers name in `comboBox2`. Based on the selected name `textbox` will return `CustomerID` and Date of Allocation values.
Following are the code for that:

```
   private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if(comboBox2.SelectedIndex>0)
            {
                con = new SqlCeConnection(s);
                con.Open();
                string code = "select CustomerID,Date_of_Allocation from lockerdetails    
                where CustomerName='" + comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";

                SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(code, con);
                SqlCeCommandBuilder cmd = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(da);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                textBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerID"].ToString();
                textBox5.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date_of_Allocation"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch(SystemException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
```